# How do I split Mel Spectrogram into sub-bands of different frequency ranges

Tags: python, signal-processing, librosa, audio-processing

I'm very new to audio signal processing however, I have this assignment which I'm getting stuck.

what I'm trying to achieve is, suppose I have done feature extraction of a speech audio using Mel Spectrogram with frequency range in Mel scale (300Hz, 3400Hz).
How can I further split this into 5 non-overlapping sub-bands for example

Band 1: [300Hz, 627Hz]

Band 2: [628Hz, 1060Hz]

Band 3: [1061Hz, 1633Hz]

Band 4: [1634Hz, 2393Hz]

Band 5: [2394Hz, 3400Hz]

I've been trying to find an example of actual implementation everywhere but I couldn't find one.

It would be much appreciated if someone could provide me some advices or guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is based on an assignment, this answer will provide the tools you need (not the actual answer!).

Assuming you've used the Mel Spectrogram of librosa like here:
https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html

Then, you'll get a 2-D numpy array for the spectrogram.
For the above example, using `S.shape` gives `(128, 230)`

That means there are 128 [mel-bands](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.filters.mel.html#librosa.filters.mel) (frequency groupings) generated and 230 time groupings.

You will then need to do some [array slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp) to get the right bands. Example: `S[0:5]` gets the first five bands for all time steps. You'll need to do the math to see which bands represent which frequencies.